# phpSound - fb sign up/login Issue

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I have phpSound 1.1.0 hosted on Hostinger.in.

Everything is working fine except facebook sign up/login.
According to phpSound documentation, I believe few more instructions are missing. Here is what it says:

> Go to developers.facebook.com and create a new "Website" app. (Skip Quickstart).
>   Go to your App from "Apps", add your Site URL and copy the "App ID" and "App Secret".
>   You can now enable the Facebook Login from the Admin Panel by adding the "App ID" and "App Secret" and enabling "Facebook Login".

I have done this successfully with no luck.
My Fb app is active; here are the details:

- App domins: music.cyrilized.com
- Site URL :music.cyrilized.com/
- Client OAuth Login : Yes
- Web OAuth Login : Yes
- mbedded Browser OAuth Login : Yes
- Valid OAuth redirect URls :music.cyrilized.com/requests/connect.php

Am I wrong at Valid OAuth redirect URls?

After I click on fb button under Register it goes to fb login page (Fisrt time i.e. if i am not logged in already) :

> https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=1646200038992626&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.5%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmusic.cyrilized.com%252Frequests%252Fconnect.php%253Ffacebook%253Dtrue%26state%3D6dbff5fe5d5231436d0937003aeffc9a%26scope%3Dpublic_profile%252Cemail%26client_id%3D1646200038992626%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmusic.cyrilized.com%2Frequests%2Fconnect.php%3Ffacebook%3Dtrue%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26state%3D6dbff5fe5d5231436d0937003aeffc9a%23_%3D_&display=page

When trying to register/login by clicking on fb button again it redirects me to

> http://music.cyrilized.com/#_= _

without logging in.?

Required chmod has been appied to the neccesarry folders/files though.Is this a kind of access denied case to write profile info into Db or something? Or is it something simple which i am not able to figure out?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please use the real values on your post? None of that is confidential, but required to test and check your settings.

Comment: @roemer Thanks Roe for trying help me out, i have updated the values , please have a look.